# Primefaces components CSS customization

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

As I see in the primefaces documentation,

```
    1) To change the font-size of PrimeFaces components globally, use the `.ui-widget` style class. 
       An example with 12px font size.

        .ui-widget,
        .ui-widget .ui-widget {
               font-size: 12px !important;
         }
```

I have 2 questions on this:

1. Why is the `.ui-widget` written thrice in the above code?
2. For two different instances of `tabView` I want to customize its header background-color differently, but I couldnt find a way to do that. Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the style declaration they are comma delimiting the list of different class overrides.  Specifically this piece of css states:

Classes `ui-widget` and `ui-widget` child elements of an element that has the class `ui-widget`.

As far as the header background is considered you might not have luck using simple CSS to modify the background color as I believe that it is likely using various different 1px wide GIF or JPG images repeated as opposed to a solid contiguously declared color.

If you want to customize the default themes of the Primefaces components with your own stylesheets then you are best to look into a tool like Firebug, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ for inspecting classes, styles and modifying them real time on ANY web page that Firefox is currently viewing.  It even has built in Javascript debugging.

Answer (score 2):

> For two different instances of tabView I want to customize its header background-color differently, but I couldnt find a way to do that. Is that even possible ?

tabView, like all other PrimeFaces components has the attribute `styleClass`. Therewith you can assign your own CSS style class to a tabView instance (or any instance of a different component).

So you can create two style classes with different background colors.

xhtml:

```
<p:tabView styleClass="myClass">
   ...
</p:tabView>
```

css:

```
.myClass {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

You might need a more specific selector, read about [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little subjective, but unless you're looking to customise existing Jquery UI IDs within a pre-existing/pre-rolled Primefaces theme then you're on a bit of a hiding to nothing. PanelGroups, PanelGrids and TabViews, for example, burst their containers and not even an overflow:auto can repair it.

One of the most infurating things about the Primefaces library is how the components do not pass W3C validation, leading to hours of "Fighting the Framework".